# JVM won't close after JDialog has been disposed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jvm, jdialog

I have created an extension of `JDialog`.

```
public class ImageDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField textField;

    public ImageDialog(JFrame parent, String title, 
                        String message, BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
        super(parent, title, true);
        if (parent != null) {
            Dimension parentSize = parent.getSize();
            Point p = parent.getLocation();
            setLocation(p.x + parentSize.width / 4, p.y + parentSize.height / 4);
        }

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setModal(true);

        JPanel frame = new JPanel();
        frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        frame.add(new JLabel(message), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JLabel lblimage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bufferedImage));
        frame.add(lblimage, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        textField = new JTextField(1);

        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        getContentPane().add(frame);

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("OK");
        buttonPane.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public String getTextField() {
        return textField.getText();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
    }
}
```

It works well and does what's it supposed to do, except that jvm won't close after it's been used. I use it as follows:

```
ImageDialog dlg = new ImageDialog(new JFrame(), "Important question", "How many fluffy bunnies do you see?", img);
System.out.println(dlg.getTextField());
dlg.dispose();
```

But JVM just hangs there when the program is done. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to set for your frame `setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Or in any other place:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

After closing dialog program will exit.

For dialog you should set `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` close operation property. Dialog is frame dependent. Your program will end when you close your frame.

That's why don't forget to make your frame visible.

**EDIT**

Instead of this:

```
ImageDialog dlg = new ImageDialog(new JFrame(), "Screen captcha", "Enter the letters from the image", img);
System.out.println(dlg.getTextField());
dlg.dispose();
```

You should have sth like this:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setVisible(true);
//ideally frame should have a button that creates the dialog and sets it to visible
// no need to dispose dialog here
```

Comment: I don't want the program to exit when the dialog closes. All I want is for dialog to die and be forgotten after it's done its job and for the program to continue running. Instead the dialog hangs in the background. Also, your solution results in a thrown exception.

Comment: "except that jvm won't close after it's been used" - set this property and it will close. You JVm hangs because default behavior is HIDE_ON_CLOSE

Comment: Setting that property results in a thrown exception: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultCloseOperation must be one of: DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE, HIDE_ON_CLOSE, or DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
 at javax.swing.JDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.java:753)
 at com.browser.gui.ImageDialog.<init>(ImageDialog.java:22)
 at com.browser.core.Test.main(Test.java:19)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

Comment: edited answer. Dialog has a parent frame. You should setVisible the frame and set frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: this.getParent() doesn't have setDefaultCloseOperation method implemented.

Comment: found a very good example of what I'm trying to explain: http://darksleep.com/player/DialogExample/TestTheDialog.java.html

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work just fine in this SSCCE that uses [`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) for the dialogs as well as the frame.

> **Note:** When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM) is disposed of, the VM may terminate.

That note is important if the app. uses `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` consistently and the VM fails to terminate.  It indicates that there is a stray non-daemon thread running (amok?).  Better to find the source of that thread and take reasonable action to terminate it gracefully.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Image Dialog Test");
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(128,50,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400,100);
        f.setVisible(true);
        new ImageDialog(f, "Hi!", "Hello World", bi);
    }

    public ImageDialog(JFrame parent, String title, 
                        String message, BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
        super(parent, title, true);
        if (parent != null) {
            Dimension parentSize = parent.getSize();
            Point p = parent.getLocation();
            setLocation(p.x + parentSize.width / 4, p.y + parentSize.height / 4);
        }

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setModal(true);

        JPanel frame = new JPanel();
        frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        frame.add(new JLabel(message), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JLabel lblimage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bufferedImage));
        frame.add(lblimage, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        textField = new JTextField(1);

        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        getContentPane().add(frame);

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("OK");
        buttonPane.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public String getTextField() {
        return textField.getText();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 //Set all your:
 .DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
 //to: 
 .EXIT_ON_CLOSE
 //and if  dispose(); is the last thing to happen change it to:
 System.exit(0);
```

EDIT for comment answer:

```
 System.gc();
 dialog.setVisible(false);
```

The JVM will run as long as your program is running so I don't see the issue with that.

Comment: System.exit(0) works, except I use that dialog many times in my program. I guess that means that it will create a thread for each of them which will hang there until I do System.exit(0), which is not something that I'd like my program to do.

Comment: System.gc() will push the garbage collector...may help if used like this: System.gc(); .setVisible(false);.